# Is Microsoft List and SharePoint lists the same thing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, microsoft-lists

I always create SharePoint sites and add SharePoint list. inside the SharePoint lists i add custom content types , create power apps and power automate to automate the lists.

now today i came across the Microsoft lists, where from my Office 365 page >> i click on "Lists" >> create a new list >> and chose an existing SharePoint site, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

and what i get is exactly the same as the SharePoint list..

so can i say that Microsoft lists and SharePoint lists are the same thing? or there are differences between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint list and Microsoft list are basically the same, they both have similar functions and integration (Power Apps, Power Automated and etc.).

It means that if you want a list, you just need to create a Microsoft list, you don't need to create a whole SharePoint site to create a list. When you create a list in the SharePoint site, it is stored in your SharePoint site, on the contrary, Microsoft lists is stored in your OneDrive site.

And Microsoft Lists has its own mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially they are the same thing.  The Microsoft Lists app basically displays the Lists from your SharePoint site inside a full-screen Edge window.  It allows you to connect directly to the lists without having to browse to the asset via the actual SharePoint site.

Personally, as I work with many different lists across several different sites, I find using the app much more convenient as I have all of the lists immediately at my disposal AND they appear in a full-screen version.  There do not seem to be any limitations as to what can be done, and the app allows multiple instances so you can work with multiple lists at once.

Another feature I often use is developing the list in the app, using my personal OneDrive space.  When I am ready to make it live, I can Create a New List, from an Existing List, which basically allows me to use what I created as the template for a list that will appear on a site.

There is a mobile version of the app, though it does not seem to show the comments pane which I like to use to have a discussion about the item.  Still, it is very handy for viewing and adding items on the go.